# How to filter a pandas dataframe (efficiently) such that it extracts data from specific columns given a certain condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance, indexing

My initial dataframe looks like this.

| Class Home | Class Away | Point Home | Point Away |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 2 | 1 |
| B | A | 4 | 3 |
| C | A | 6 | 5 |
| A | C | 8 | 7 |

If I am looking at only "**A**", my condition is if column *"Class Home"* == A, I want to extract data from the same row of column *"Point Home"*. If *"Class Away"* == A, I want to extract the data from column *"Point Away".* The resulting dataframe should look something like this:

| Class | Point |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2 |
| A | 3 |
| A | 5 |
| A | 8 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 4 |
| C | 6 |
| C | 7 |

How can I do this efficiently?

I have tried using dictionaries to store data of each Class by looping over the dataframe using itertuples but not sure if it is efficient for large datasets. Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the Index, [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
out = (
 df.set_axis(df.columns.str.split(expand=True), axis=1)
   .stack()
   .sort_values(by='Class', key=lambda s: s.ne('A'),
                kind='stable', ignore_index=True)
)
```

Output:

```
  Class  Point
0     A      2
1     A      3
2     A      5
3     A      8
4     B      1
5     B      4
6     C      6
7     C      7
```

Answer (score 0):

With combination of [`numpy.stack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) + [`numpy.reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) to sequentially stack `Home` and `Away` row values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.hstack((df.filter(like='Home'), df.filter(like='Away')))
                  .reshape(-1, 2), columns=['Class', 'Point'])\
    .sort_values(by='Class')
```

---

```
  Class Point
0    A      2
3    A      3
5    A      5
6    A      8
1    B      1
2    B      4
4    C      6
7    C      7
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Class Home': ["A", "B", "C", "A"], 'Class Away': ["B", "A", "A", "C"],
                   'Point Home': [2, 4, 6, 8], 'Point Away': [1, 3, 5, 7],})

l =[]
for let in df['Class Home'].unique():
    m = ( df[['Class Home', 'Class Away']].eq(let) ).astype(int)
    e = df[['Point Home', 'Point Away']]
    a = pd.DataFrame( np.multiply(m, e).sum(axis=1) ).rename(columns={0:'Point'})
    a['Class'] = let
    l.append(a[a['Point']>0])

r = ( pd.concat(l).reset_index(drop=True) ) [['Class', 'Point']]

print(r)
```

```
  Class  Point
0     A      2
1     A      3
2     A      5
3     A      8
4     B      1
5     B      4
6     C      6
7     C      7
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using `pd.wide_to_long()`

```
pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(),i = 'index',j = 't',stubnames=['Class','Point'],suffix=r'.*').reset_index(drop=True).sort_values('Class')
```

Output:

```
  Class  Point
0     A      2
3     A      8
5     A      3
6     A      5
1     B      4
4     B      1
2     C      6
7     C      7
```